# How to merge/delete snapshots with libvirt-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to write some Python code that uses `libvirt-python` to manage external snapshots with the KVM APIs.
I'm not sure of what to do in order to delete (aka merge) a certain snapshot. Let's say we have mainly 2 case in the following scenario: `base <- snap_a <- snap-b <- top` (as shown in [this webpage](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/I_created_an_external_snapshot,_but_libvirt_will_not_let_me_delete_or_revert_to_it)).

1. I want to merge `snap_a` and `snap_b` (b is the active one). The result should have `base` as backing file in the snapshot chain.
2. I want to merge `base` and `snap_a` (none of them is active). The result should keep `snap_b` as active snapshot, which has `base` as backing file.

In the first case I lost my `base` backing file, while in the second one i got this error: `Failed to merge snapshot: invalid argument: active commit requested but '/var/lib/nova/instances/b9c9cd3b-1102-4084-a7a9-6e85c179ac9c/disk.snap_system_1610446663' is not active` (`snap_system_numbers` here is like snap_a in my example).

This is my merging function:

```
def snapshot_merge(instance_name: str, snapshot_name: str):
    # Getting the connection to qemu
    conn, dom = open_qemu_connection(instance_name)
    if conn is not None and dom is not None:
        logging.info(
                     'Merging domain {} from snapshot {}'
                     .format(instance_name, snapshot_name))
        # Merge snapshot (Block commit, first phase)
        # Get the vda path from my custom function
        disk_path = get_vda_path(dom)
        top = disk_path+'.'+snapshot_name
        disk = 'vda'
        bandwith = 0
        # Check if snapshot in input is the active/current one. Also setting flags
        snapshot = dom.snapshotCurrent()
        if snapshot.getName() == snapshot_name:
            bc_flags = (libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCK_COMMIT_ACTIVE
                        + libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCK_COMMIT_SHALLOW)
        else:
            bc_flags = 0
        try:
            dom.blockCommit(disk,
                            None,
                            top,
                            bandwith,
                            bc_flags)
            logging.info('Snapshot merged')
        except libvirt.libvirtError as e:
            logging.info('Failed to merge snapshot: %s' % e)
            close_qemu_connection(conn)
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=ERR_MERGE)
        # Merge snapshot (Pivoting, second phase)
        piv_flags = libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_BLOCK_JOB_ABORT_PIVOT
        # Wait for ready state
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            dom.blockJobAbort(disk, piv_flags)
            logging.info('Snapshot pivoted')
            snapshot_delete(dom, snapshot_name, top)
            return {"snapshot_name": snapshot_name}
        except libvirt.libvirtError as e:
            logging.info('Failed to pivot snapshot: %s' % e)
            # TODO snapshot_delete(dom, snapshot_name, top)
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=ERR_PIVOT)
        finally:
            close_qemu_connection(conn)
    else:
        logging.info('Process failed')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=ERR_CONN)
```